# Typeahead 0.11.1 Mouse over and keyboard conflict when viewing dropdown search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, typeahead.js

I have implemented Twitter's Typeahead.js functionality for showing search result suggestions, it works fine but the problem comes when I use the keyboard to highlight a suggestion and then move the cursor on a different suggestion. Here are some pictures explaining the issue:

[image: Keyboard movement]

[image: Mouse movement]

How can I remove the keyboard selection when the mouse cursor hovers on another selection and also if the mouse is already hovering on one suggestion, if I press up/down on the keyboard, the mouse selection disappears and the selection moves up/down respectively?

**HTML/Javascript/JQuery/AJAX**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
        <div class="input-group search-bar-nav">
            <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Buscar trabajos" name="key" id="search-input" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="input-group-btn search-button">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    var jobs = [];

    var throttledRequest = _.debounce(function (query, syncResults, asyncResults){
        var url = 'quicksearch?key=' + query;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data){
                var jobs = [];

                _.each(data, function (item, ix, list){
                    jobs.push(item);
                });

                asyncResults(jobs);
            }
        });
    }, 300);

    $('#search-input').typeahead({ highlight: true }, {
        source: function (query, syncResults, asyncResults){
            throttledRequest(query, syncResults, asyncResults);
        },
        display: 'title',
        templates: {
            suggestion: function (data){
                var result = '<div class="tt-job-result">'
                            + '<div class="tt-job-title">' + data.title + '</div>'
                            + '<div class="tt-job-company">' + data.companyName + '</div>'
                            + '</div>';
                return result;
            }
        },
        name: 'results',
        limit: 10,

    });
    $(".tt-hint").addClass("form-control");
    $('.tt-hint').width($('#search-input').parent().outerWidth() + 39);
    $('#search-input').width($('#search-input').parent().outerWidth() + 39);
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #8a6d3b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #66512c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #a94442;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #843534;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #3c763d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-input:focus,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #2b542c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #67b168;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
select.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
textarea.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
textarea.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
select.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}
textarea.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
textarea.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-input,
select[multiple].input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: auto;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-input,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead {
  display: table-cell !important;
  float: left;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  color: #999999;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
  z-index: 2;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[disabled],
.twitter-typeahead .tt-input[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .twitter-typeahead .tt-input {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
}
.tt-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.tt-menu .tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tt-menu .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #262626;
}
.tt-menu .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor a {
  color: #262626;
}
.tt-menu .tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}

.tt-menu .tt-suggestion:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #262626;
}

.tt-menu .tt-suggestion:hover a {
  color: #262626;
}

.tt-job-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tt-job-result {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tt-job-company {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

BTW I am using Bootstrap 3 (Which is not compatible with Typeahead v0.11.1) hence the long CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
    $('.twitter-typeahead').on('mouseover', '.tt-suggestion', function(event){
        $('.tt-tag').removeClass('tt-cursor');
        $(this).addClass('tt-tag-hover');
    });

    $('.twitter-typeahead').bind('typeahead:cursorchange', function (ev, suggestion){
        $('.tt-tag').removeClass('tt-tag-hover');
    });
```

to your script, and add the following class to the css, whilst removing the `.tt-menu tt-suggestion:hover` class

```
.tt-tag-hover:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #262626;
}
```